# Negative lookahead regex not working

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

```
input1="caused/VBN by/IN thyroid disorder"
```

Requirement: find word `"caused"` that is followed by slash followed by any number of capital alphabets -- and not followed by space + `"by/IN`.

In the example above `"caused/VBN"` is followed by `" by/IN"`, so 'caused' should not match.

```
input2="caused/VBN thyroid disorder"
```

`"by/IN"` doesn't follow caused, so it should match

```
regex="caused/[A-Z]+(?![\\s]+by/IN)"
```

`caused/[A-Z]+` -- word 'caused' + / + one or more capital letters
`(?![\\s]+by)` -- negative lookahead - not matching space and by

Below is a simple method that I used to test

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String input = "caused/VBN by/IN thyroid disorder";

    String regex = "caused/[A-Z]+(?![\\s]+by/IN)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Output: `caused/VB`

I don't understand why my negative lookahead regex is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include a word boundary in your regular expression:

```
String regex = "caused/[A-Z]+\\b(?![\\s]+by/IN)";
```

Without it you can get a match, but not what you were expecting:

```
"caused/VBN by/IN thyroid disorder";
 ^^^^^^^^^
 this matches because "N by" doesn't match "[\\s]+by"
```

Comment: The brackets around `\\s` are unnecessary, no?

Comment: Yes, they are completely unnecessary.

Comment: +1 - Note that a possessive plus would also do the trick: `caused/[A-Z]++(?![\s]+by/IN)`.

Comment: thanks for your comments. 

>> this matches because "N by" doesn't match "[\\s]+by"
this makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

The character class []+ match will be adjusted (via backtracking) so that the lookahead will match.

What you have to do is stop the backtracking so that the expression []+ is fully matched.
This can be done a couple of different ways.

1. A positive lookahead, followed by a consumption
   `"caused(?=(/[A-Z]+))\\1(?!\\s+by/IN)"`
2. A standalone sub-expression
   `"caused(?>/[A-Z]+)(?!\\s+by/IN)"`
3. A possesive quantifier
   `"caused/[A-Z]++(?!\\s+by/IN)"`

Comment: thanks for your answers
Your possesive quantifier suggestion is great -- I need to read up a little to understand your other suggestions. thanks much!